# how to connect mysql database using port datareceived event

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

Currently I'm using C# code to access MySQL database  in my application. 
I want to access the database by firing data accessing method in the port data received event.I have already written the data access method which is fired the serial port data received event when a message is received by the modem.but I can't access the data base. It gives an error message:

```
  unable to connect any specified MySQL hosts
```

When I call the data accessing method using button click event without letting it to fire in the serial port data received event, it works correctly.How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you provide some code? If you are working with WinForms could it be beacause of multi-threading. DataReceived event is working on a second thread not in the main. Maybe you could check debugging what is getting the connector as connectionString.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to check the connection between you and the MySQL Server by trying to connect via the mysql command line tool or mysql workbench.

If you can't connect, there might be some connectivity issued forced due to a firewall or mysql not being started.